# Unable to upload APK to in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I have recently upgraded to the 'Blaze" plan of Firebase. I am trying to test a release APK using the Firebase Test Lab, but every time I upload an APK, I get this.

> The file could not be uploaded to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). This issue might be caused by incorrect GCS permissions.

How to solve this problem? Do I need to change some settings in the project?

PS - I know this is specifically not a programming related question. I have to resort to SO, as even after putting this issue to Firebase support, I have got no solution.

Comment: *firebaser here* Hey Aritra, sorry to hear about this problem. There are no other reports of this being a broader issue, so we'll need to troubleshoot your specific case. Can you share the project id?

Comment: Sure. But I cannot disclose the project id here. Can we discuss over email?

Comment: In that case, can you share your support case ID? I searched our system but can't seem to find it. Alternatively: just follow up on the support case and explain that I've asked you to reach out.

Comment: I have contacted the support about the issue once again. Thanks. Hope it gets resolved soon.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Here is my support ID, 3-5660000014198. The support is not able to help me resolve it. I am unable to test anything in Firebase Test Lab.

Comment: Hi there, I have the same issue

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: This problem got automatically solved after a few days and I changed nothing from my part. But now when I try to run a test, it never starts. Shows "Failed to create test matrix" everytime.

Comment: This issue is still going on @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Given that this question is 4 years old and the reporting dev indicated the problem was solved back then, it seems unlikely that it is **ongoing**. The same problem or another problem may have reoccured, in which case I'd recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

*Firebase Test Lab team member here*

Projects that were using Test Lab on the Blaze plan prior to Septmber 29th own the storage bucket used for app and test result storage. If such a project is downgraded to the Spark plan and has its billing account removed, that storage bucket may become unwritable.

You can tell whether or not you are using your own storage bucket by examining the path on the request to `clients6.google.com/upload/storage/` from your browser. If it is **not** something like `clients6.google.com/upload/storage/.../test-lab-(id)` then you may have problems uploading APKs on the Spark plan.

If that is the case, try creating a new project. We are working on a fix so that this will not be necessary.

Comment: Looks like the ongoing issue that was causing "401 - Invalid Credentials" is now resolved.

Comment: Still not fixed? Creating a new project is also not working.

Comment: @MichaelLawrence Facing the same issue. When can we expect this to be fixed? Our dev team is stuck because of this. Please provide an ETA or a work around for this.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for coming a bit late i faced the issue recently but solved it simply my disabling a VPN service i turned on, I was using it a minute then turned on my vpn to do something else only for the issue to start after that it wasn't intentional but i guessed it was the vpn and i was right everything was back to normal after i turn off the vpn.
I think this has to be because google cloud storage work in the background based on region just like firebase bucket will asked to used a storage location bucket when creating a project

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem after 2 days .

looks to be due to missing permissions for users.
my permision was **Viewer Admin** and i changed to **Editor** rule and works fine.

for more inoformation :
[Firebase IAM permissions sections for Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#test-lab)